# New figures not being included in document

Tags: graphics

I have a list of images in an image folder with all in pdf format. However, I recently added a new image an now the LaTeX console does not recognise it and gives the file not found error.The format I used up till now and in the past has worked.

```
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
\begin{figure}[htc]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{folderName/imagename}
\caption{Research Design Constituents}
\label{fig:6}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Mmmm, you're using an unrecognized float placement `c`. That shouldn't be a problem though.

Comment: What's the purpose of `\floatplacement{figure}{H}`?

Comment: It is really hard to figure out what is going on from the given information.  Did you check the obvious problems, like spelling of the filename, incl. uppercase/lowercase letters, etc.?